# Python, PyTorch. I'm trying to run different microsoft/git models using Pipeline, but I'm getting an error: raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'input_ids'

Tags: python, pytorch, pipeline, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

It used to work fine, but stopped working when I switched to SUDO and the SUDO version of PyTorch.

here's my code

```
import torch
import requests
from PIL import Image
from transformers import pipeline

image = Image.open('img.jpg')
pipe = pipeline("image-to-text", model="microsoft/git-base",device = 0)
print(pipe(image))
```

and my error

```
The model 'GitForCausalLM' is not supported for image-to-text. Supported models are ['BlipForConditionalGeneration', 'Blip2ForConditionalGeneration', 'VisionEncoderDecoderModel'].
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\AutoKey\app.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(pipe(image))
  File "D:\Programs\Conda\envs\GPTKey\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\image_to_text.py", line 99, in __call__
    return super().__call__(images, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programs\Conda\envs\GPTKey\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\base.py", line 1119, in __call__
    return self.run_single(inputs, preprocess_params, forward_params, postprocess_params)
  File "D:\Programs\Conda\envs\GPTKey\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\base.py", line 1126, in run_single
    model_outputs = self.forward(model_inputs, **forward_params)
  File "D:\Programs\Conda\envs\GPTKey\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\base.py", line 1025, in forward
    model_outputs = self._forward(model_inputs, **forward_params)
  File "D:\Programs\Conda\envs\GPTKey\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\image_to_text.py", line 113, in _forward
    inputs = model_inputs.pop(self.model.main_input_name)
  File "D:\Programs\Conda\envs\GPTKey\lib\_collections_abc.py", line 962, in pop
    value = self[key]
  File "D:\Programs\Conda\envs\GPTKey\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 1106, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'input_ids'
```

I enabled the mode for CPU again, the same error comes out. Tried other models, they work quite well because they have ready python code attached. Microsoft GIT doesn't have that, so I use Pipeline.

When I try to use GIT using this code (got it here: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/model_doc/git#transformers.GitVisionModel)

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from transformers import AutoProcessor, GitVisionModel
processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/git-base")
model = GitVisionModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/git-base")
url = "http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000039769.jpg"
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
inputs = processor(images=image, return_tensors="pt")
outputs = model(**inputs)
last_hidden_state = outputs.last_hidden_state
```

A message comes up that it looks like I need to train the model.
Not well versed in PyTorch, just trying to get the models to fit.

Comment: UPD: I didn't solve this problem, but I got out of it. Stopped using Pipeline, this guide for the very young helped me.
https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/GIT/Inference_with_GIT_for_image_video_captioning_and_image_video_QA.ipynb